# how to populate java array

Tags: java, arrays

i want this code  to ask user to populate the array and when the array length is complete it must display the filled numbers and break the code im getting the error :

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at classes.Classes.main(Classes.java:32)
C:\Users\realshane\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)**

here is the code :

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    
    int [] myArray = new int[10];
    
    int i;
    int count = 1;
    
    while( count < myArray.length){
        for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Populate Array : ");
            myArray[i] = in.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        
        
        if( count >= myArray.length){
            for(int values: myArray){
                System.out.println(myArray[i]);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Change `System.out.println(myArray[i]);` to `System.out.println(values);`.

Comment: When the `for (i = 0; ...` loop ends, `i` has value `myArray.length`, so when you later do `println(myArray[i])`, the value is out of range. This is one of the reasons why you should be declaring `i` as part of the loop, not before it, so the stale value of `i` cannot be (mis)used: `for (int i = 0; ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [] myArray = new int[10];
    int count = 0;

    while( count < myArray.length){
      System.out.println("Element at index "+ count);
      myArray[count] = in.nextInt();

      count++;
    }

    System.out.println("Displaying array : ");
    for(int values: myArray){
      System.out.println(values);
    }
  }
}
```